# pass list of my objects through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have a list of objects that I have created. I need to pass it to another activity. It's not working

```
List<Dog> myDogs = ...
intent.putExtra(ALL_MY_DOGS,myDogs);
```

I get the compile error:

```
The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the
arguments (String, List<Dog>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. I was passing a list instead of an ArrayList.

Comment: The reason this fixes the problem is because `List` is not `Serializable` but `ArrayList` is. The documentation ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable) ) shows that there is an implementation of `Intent.putExtra(String, Serializable)`.

Comment: So that means I should read it with `getSerializableExtra`, correct?